# Merge one table field that is email in three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union, group-concat

I want a query to get the result of merging one field, email in three different tables from the same database, how do I do that?

Below is my code

```
SELECT * FROM luckydraw_weekone 
LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id 
LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id;
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should use correct tags. This ain't PHP

Comment: To clarify are you saying the email is stored in all three tables and you want to just get the email as the result of this query?

Comment: Maybe this `SELECT * FROM luckydraw_weekone LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.email = luckydraw_weektwo.email LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.email= participants.email;`

Comment: can i display results vertically?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT table_names.column_names FROM luckydraw_weekone 
LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id 
LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id";
```

Your code looks fine to me. I usually use the required column names instead of `*` . Try it or share some more code if it doesn't work.

Comment: You could use GROUP_CONCAT for this.
`$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_names.column_names SEPERATOR ',') FROM luckydraw_weekone 
LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id 
LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id";`

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weekone.Email,luckydraw_weektwo.Email,participants.Email, SEPERATOR ',') FROM luckydraw_weekone LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id

Comment: You have to add GROUP_CONCAT for each of the column name like this - 
`$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weekone.Email), GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weektwo.Email), GROUP_CONCAT(participants.Email) FROM luckydraw_weekone LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id";` 
Try Now.

Comment: i have one more thing to ask,i have one registered users table in it which contains emails of registered users, i want to check all emails from above 3 tables are which are existing in user tables

Comment: i have one more thing to ask,i have one registered users table in it which contains emails of registered users, i want to check all emails from above 3 tables are which are existing in user tables

Comment: `$query_run = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run) {
$query2 = "SELECT something FROM registeredUserTable where registeredUserEmail = '.$row['Email'].'";
//RUN QUERY
}'

Hope this Works.

Comment: no,it doesnt work i have put the query here it is $query_run = mysql_query($query); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run) { $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users where mail = '.$row['Email'].'"; //RUN QUERY }

Comment: I only need to list all existing email id from users by comparing with luckydraw_weekone luckydraw_weektwo and participants

Comment: I only need to list all existing email id from users by comparing with luckydraw_weekone luckydraw_weektwo and participants

Comment: here are my two queries

Comment: $query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( luckydraw_weekone.Email, luckydraw_weektwo.Email, participants.Email )
FROM luckydraw_weekone
LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id
LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id";

$query_run = mysql_query($query); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run) { $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users where mail = '.$row['Email'].'"; //RUN QUERY }

Comment: first i merge 3 tables emails ids in a single column and then i check and display emails which are already existing in users table.

Comment: RUN QUERY as in you have to write the code to run that query!

Comment: `$query2 = "SELECT * FROM users where mail='.$row['Email'].'"
$query_run2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query_run2)){
echo $row2['username']; // Or any column name
}
`
See if this works

Comment: $query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( luckydraw_weekone.Email, luckydraw_weektwo.Email, participants.Email )
FROM luckydraw_weekone
LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id
LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id";
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$display_string = "<table border=\"1\">";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
 $display_string .= "<td>$row[0]</td>";
 $display_string .= "<td>$row[1]</td>";
 $display_string .= "<td>$row[2]</td>";
 $display_string .= "</tr>";
}

Comment: how do i get list of existing users by comparing it with user mails

Comment: how do i get list of existing users by comparing it with user mails

Comment: Ok.but still i am not getting the desired output,the code above shows me unexisted users as well in the existing list.

Comment: Ok.but still i am not getting the desired output,the code above shows me unexisted users as well in the existing list.

Comment: i only have this last question.

Comment: @Andriy M : Thanks. I'm new here too.

Comment: @user3172127 : Better ask a new question rather than commenting. This is all I know. Good Luck.

Comment: @user3172127: Well, if the problem is not solved, then maybe some vital information is missing from your question. In fact, your question *is* rather vague at this point. Please edit your question to provide an example: data samples and the desired result (you might also need to explain the desired result).

Answer (score 0):

u use * so it output id as three columns ,if u only need id in one column

```
SELECT a.column_names FROM luckydraw_weekone a
LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo b ON a.id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN participants c ON b.id = c.id
```

using alias make it easier to read

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( luckydraw_weekone.Email),GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weektwo.Email), GROUP_CONCAT(participants.Email) FROM luckydraw_weekone LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id";
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$display_string = "<table border=\"1\">"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
 $display_string .= "<td>$row[0]</td>"; 
 $display_string .= "<td>$row[1]</td>"; 
 $display_string .= "<td>$row[2]</td>"; 
 $display_string .= "</tr>"; 
 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail='.$row[0].' OR mail='.$row[1].' OR mail='.$row[2].'";
 $qry_result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()); 
 $display_string_user = "<table border=\"1\">"; 
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result2)){ 
 $display_string_user .= "<td>$row[0]</td>"; 
 $display_string_user .= "<td>$row[1]</td>"; 
 // and all details you want to add
 $display_string_user .= "</tr>"; 
 }
 } 
 $display_string .= "</table>"; 
 $display_string_user .= "</table>"; 
 echo $display_string;
 echo $display_string_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave to use `UNION` instead of `JOIN`

```
SELECT email FROM luckydraw_weekone
UNION 
SELECT email FROM luckydraw_weektwo
UNION 
SELECT email FROM participants
```

If you want in one field only then use below query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email) 
FROM (SELECT email FROM luckydraw_weekone
      UNION 
      SELECT email FROM luckydraw_weektwo
      UNION 
      SELECT email FROM participants
) AS A
```